# mysql appends my domain to my username

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to access a mysql server remotely, I have all the login details but whenever I try to connect, it always adds my current IP or domain to the username, thus preventing me to login.  Furthermore, I don't have terminal access to the server.

From the command line I try something like:

```
mysql -h example.com -u the_username -p
```

It returns with the error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'the_username'@'my_isp_address.com'
```

trying:

```
mysql -h example.com -u the_username@example.com -p
```

doesn't make a difference, it just returns:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'the_username@example.com'@'my_isp_address.com'
```

How can I get through this?

Comment: Take a look at the `mysql.user` table. Every user may have multiple rows for the same name but with different hosts. This way you have more control over who can login from where. To allow a user to login from anywhere, the host must be `%`.

Comment: Can't look at that table, until I can login.

Comment: "I'm trying to access a mysql server remotely" Apparently, the server is not setup to allow connections from your host. First you have to login locally (e.g. by SSH-ing in to the host, then connecting to the db locally) or from an allowed host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how MySql works, you have to specify domain(or ip address) for your records.

If you want to use IP addresses, you will need to enable [--skip-name-resolve](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-name-resolve) poperty

More info here [DNS Lookup Optimization and the Host Cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/host-cache.html)

Another option grant access for all hosts for user:

```
GRANT SELECT ON `db`.`table` TO 'user_name'@'%'
```

Use (%) sign.

But if you don't have access to server or DB, you will have to find server/db administrator, to configure it for you.

Comment: --skip-name-resolve sounds promising, but in my version (5.5.16) doesn't seem to have that option.  Also I can't do any queries, such as the GRANT, until I am able to login. :)

Comment: @Jahmic Well, than i don't think that it will be possible for you to connect to this server

Comment: I eventually got in the phpymadmin interface.  Still, would have liked to have gotten in through console app.